# Subcategories in vertical navigation are hidden and not displayed properly

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Can someone please tell me how to solve the problem. I recently tried to make a navigation menu for my website which opens subcategories on hover. But the problem is that the subcategory `LI` items are not displayed properly, they are displayed behind the other objects and are not visible. I tried to put `z-index` and some other solutions to fix the problem, but I havent managed to do that

Here's a picture that will show you whats the exact problem 
http://s27.postimg.org/soa5vro1f/Untitled.jpg

This is the CSS and JS code i used for it, only CSS Code is here:

```
<style>
  #menu-v li, #menu-v a {zoom:1;} /* Hacks for IE6, IE7 */
  #menu-v, #menu-v ul
  {
    width: 180px; /* Main Menu Item widths */
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top:none;
    position: relative; font-size:0;
    list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; display:block;
  }

  /* Top level menu links style
  ---------------------------------------*/
  .showMe
  {
    z-index: 99999999999;
  }
  #menu-v li
  {
    list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;
  }
  #menu-v li a
  {
    font: normal 12px Arial;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: block;
    /*overflow: auto; force hasLayout in IE7 */
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height:26px;
    padding-left:26px;            
  }
  #menu-v ul li a
  {
  }

  #menu-v li a.arrow:hover
  {
    background-image:url(arrowon.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 97% 50%;
  }

  /*Sub level menu items
  ---------------------------------------*/
  #menu-v li ul
  {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px; /*Sub Menu Items width */
    visibility:hidden;
    z-index: 9999999999;
  }

  #menu-v a.arrow
  {
    background-image:url(arrow.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 97% 50%;
  }
  #menu-v li:hover, #menu-v li.onhover
  {
    background-position:0 -62px;
  }
  #menu-v ul li
  {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.86);
    background-image:none;
  }
  #menu-v ul li:hover, #menu-v ul li.onhover
  {
    background: #eeeeee;
    background-image:none;
  }

  /* Holly Hack for IE \
  * html #menu-v  li
  {
    float:left;
    height: 1%;
  }
  * html #menu-v  li a
  {
    height: 1%;
  }*/
  /* End */
</style>
```

And this is part of the ul list, the JS code is not included:

```
<ul id="menu-v">
  <li><a class=" arrow" href=""><strong></strong></a>
    <ul style="left: 180px; top: 0px; display: none;" class=" sub showMe">
      <li ><a href=""><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Преносни компјутери</a></li>
      <li ><a href=""><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Опрема за преносни компјутери</a></li>
      <li ><a href=""><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Таблет компјутери (Tablet PC)</a></li>
    </ul>    
  </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple problems here:

### 1. NO INLINE STYLES!

As a rule of thumb, NEVER EVER EVER EVER EVER EVER EVER put styles inline. It is hideous and hard to debug and can't be overridden easily by other CSS. One style in particular, your `display:none` in your submenu `<ul>` is causing you grief here.

---

### 2. Use display:none in your CSS for your submenu, not visibility:hidden

So to remedy this, you put it in your CSS:

```
#menu-v li ul
{
    display:none;
    /*visibility:hidden <----NO!*/
}
```

---

### 3. Use li:hover to show the submenu

```
#menu-v li:hover ul
{
    display:block;
}
```

Voila!

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qn6ob6ct/)

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake i posted the actual list, its like you said id should be, but thers some problem it doesnt work

Comment: It still doesnt work, the problem is iam giving u just a part of the website and the css and the list because i cant give u the whole website. The website is in creation progress, check it [link]anhoch.amaconet.com, the navigation on the left side iam trying to make to be shown on the left side of the BOX div while iam hovering with the mouse, but the subcategory is somehow hidden behind the image slider and i cant find a way to solve it

Comment: I'm looking at the site and the image you provided and the navigation systems are different. I'm seeing an expansion navigation, rather than a floating ul submenu.

Comment: Yes i decided to change the navigation instead expanding down... to be shown to the right of the main category, but the subcategories are hiding behind and i cant find the reason why i tried changing z-index overflow display and it still show behind the image slider. I tried to expand the menu box dix with categories and remove everyhing to right, and the subcategories are visible only inside that div where the lists are located, i would like them to be shown like on the TOP FIXED navigation but instead dropdown, they need to be shown to the right